# How to center legs when powerlifting?

Tags: legs

Following a previous post, I find the issue I have when squatting is that my legs are not equal distance from the center of my hips. So, how could I make sure that this happens?

Comment: Do you mean you're shifting your weight over to one side when you squat down?

Comment: Or are your hips off-centre when you are standing up?

Comment: I think it's not @DavidScarlett

Comment: Not exactlyu, altho that used to happen before @DeeV